# Get reference of all modules in a page from a module DNN

Tags: c#, asp.net, module, dotnetnuke

Is it possible to get the references of all the modules on the current page from a module?
Like for example on a button click I could for example list all the Types of the DNN modules loaded on the page without hitting the database.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of DNN, there are some classes applied to each module that you could use to determine where each module is.  In newer versions, there is an element wrapping each module with the classes `DnnModule DnnModule-ModuleName DnnModule-2134` where `ModuleName` is the name of the module, without any spaces or other special characters, and `2134` is the module's ID.

This, of course, won't include any modules which are on the page but not visible to the current user (which is probably what you want, but still worth noting).